# UserControl не отображается в дизайнере

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, usercontrol

Есть `UserControl`

Вот его разметка

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication22.RatingBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication22"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="ratingBar" Loaded="ratingBar_Loaded">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="RatingBarDefaultStyle.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl ItemsPanel="{Binding PanelTemplate, ElementName=ratingBar}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons, ElementName=ratingBar}"
                  ItemTemplate="{Binding ButtonTemplate, ElementName=ratingBar}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

Код я приводить не стал, потому что его много и я не знаю что тут может пригодиться.

Суть вот в чем. Контрол должен отрисовывать некие объекты по количеству равному значению некоторого DependencyProperty (по умолчанию 5).

Так вот, в рантайме все отлично работает, но в дизайнере контрол не отрисовывается. Помогите разобраться.

**UPD**

Привожу код RatingBarDefaultStyle.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication22">
    <Style TargetType="local:RatingBar">
        <Setter Property="PanelTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ButtonTemplate" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:RatingButton">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**UPD2**

Привожу код свойств для темплейтов

```
public DataTemplate ButtonTemplate
{
    get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ButtonTemplateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ButtonTemplateProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTemplateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(RatingBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(DataTemplate)));

public ItemsPanelTemplate PanelTemplate
{
    get { return (ItemsPanelTemplate)GetValue(PanelTemplateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PanelTemplateProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty PanelTemplateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("PanelTemplate", typeof(ItemsPanelTemplate), typeof(RatingBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(ItemsPanelTemplate)));
```

Полагаю, дело в дефолтных значениях для свойств зависимостей. Они по умолчанию равны null, а должны иметь какое то дефолтное значение. Не знаю пока че с этим делать.

Comment: Если контрол внутри себя содержит другие контролы, он скорее всего и не будет отрисовываться. У меня например не отрисовывается.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda глупость. Должен рисоваться.

Comment: @PavelMayorov у меня например на юзер контроле который содержит другие юзер контролы, в дизайне он рисует значок - желтый треугольник со знаком восклицания, может это и я накосячил, ибо не любитель wpf

Comment: @ParanoidPanda это значит что произошла ошибка при создании контрола. Она не связана с содержимым контрола.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, так в чем может быть дело? Восклицательных знаков у меня нет. Значит, как я полагаю, логика создания этих самых контролов не срабатывает в дизайнере. Но почему - непонятно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, почитайте UPD и UPD2

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что подключать стили надо самому контролу. а не тем кто его использует?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я так не думаю. Подключать стили или не подключать - дело пользователя. Но дефолтный то стиль должен быть.

Comment: WPF так не думает.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, все айтемы, которые должны отображаться, чисто абстрактные. Стилем задается контрол, который будет их представлять. Если вы не зададите стиль элементов для листбокса, то у вас отобразятся названия типа элементов. Это есть дефолтное отображение. Короче я не понимаю вас. К чему вы клоните?

Answer (score 1):

WPF не поддерживает подключение стилей по умолчанию в самом контроле. Кроме того, у таких стилей по умолчанию есть еще одна проблема: явно заданный пользователем стиль отменит **все** ваши настройки по умолчанию вместо того чтобы перекрывать их по одной.

Вместо использования стилей разместите ваши шаблоны в словаре ресурсов после чего укажите в качестве значения по умолчанию при создании `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за замечание, только это не решило мою проблему.